# How can I binary search a String date in a string of dates in C?

Tags: c, string, date, search, binary

I'm having a problem on using binary search algorithm in an array of string date with format YYYY-MM-DD

1. **key** - the date that the algorithm is looking for.
2. ***dates** - array of stringdates
3. **numRows** - number of elements in **(*dates)**

---

```
int binarySearchDate(StrDate key, StrDate* dates, int numRows) {

  int i, left = 0, mid, right, res = -1;
  StrDate transformedKey, * dummy = dates;
  transformKey(key, transformedKey);


  right = numRows - 1;
  while (left <= right) {

    mid = left + (right - 1) / 2;
    printf("key: %s date: %s\n", transformedKey, dummy[mid]);
    if (strcmp(transformedKey, dummy[mid]) == 0)
      res = 0;

    // Check if key is present at mid
    if (res == 0)
      return mid;
    // If key is bigger, ignore left half
    if (strcmp(transformedKey, dummy[mid]) > 0)
      left = mid + 1;

    // If key is smaller, ignore right half
    else
      right = mid - 1;
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: Please show a [mcve] including input and expected vs. actual output.

Comment: Note: Better code would call `strcmp()` once and save the result than call it twice.

Answer (score 1):

Change `mid = left + (right - 1) / 2;` to `mid = left + (right - left) / 2;`